# Возможно ли как то оптимизировать код?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Пока еще не силен в js. Написал работающий код, но мне кажется что может быть его можно как то сократить. Я думаю что код ужасный. Хотя и работает.

Подскажите что можно сделать лучше. Именно то что касается JS части.

Работает только добавление и удаление. Когда нажимаешь добавление появляется корзина.

JavaScript

```
//Калькулятор
  $(".add-1").on("click", function () {
    var button = $(this);
    var cart = $('.offer__cart');
    var oldValue = button.closest('.offer__block__calc').find("input").val();
    var text = button.find('i').text();
    var price = $('#price-small').text();
    var noActive = $('.offer__cart__count--1').closest('.active');
    noActive.removeClass('no-active');
    if (text == "+") {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
      cart.fadeIn();
      cart.find('.offer__cart__count--1 span').text(newVal);
      $('.offer__cart__sum--1 span').text(newVal * price)
    } else {
      if (oldValue > 0) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        cart.find('.offer__cart__count--1 span').text(newVal);
        $('.offer__cart__sum--1 span').text(newVal * price);
        if (newVal == 0) {
          noActive.addClass('no-active');
        }
      } else {
        newVal = 0;
        noActive.addClass('no-active');
      }
    }
    button.closest('.offer__block__calc').find("input").val(newVal);
  });

  $(".add-2").on("click", function () {
    var button = $(this);
    var cart = $('.offer__cart');
    var oldValue = button.closest('.offer__block__calc').find("input").val();
    var text = button.find('i').text()
    var price = $('#price-big').text();
    var noActive = $('.offer__cart__count--2').closest('.active');
    noActive.removeClass('no-active');

    if (text == "+") {
      var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
      cart.fadeIn();
      cart.find('.offer__cart__count--2 span').text(newVal);
      $('.offer__cart__sum--2 span').text(newVal * price)
    } else {
      if (oldValue > 0) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        cart.find('.offer__cart__count--2 span').text(newVal);
        $('.offer__cart__sum--2 span').text(newVal * price);
        if (newVal == 0) {
          noActive.addClass('no-active');
        }
      } else {
        newVal = 0;
        noActive.addClass('no-active');
      }
    }

    button.closest('.offer__block__calc').find("input").val(newVal);
  });

  $('.offer__block__calc-1 input').keyup(function(){
    var curr = $(this);
    var currValue = $(this).val();
    $('.offer__cart__count--1').closest('.no-active').removeClass('no-active');
    var price = $('.offer__cart__price__clothes').text();
    $('.offer__cart').fadeIn();
    $('.offer__cart__count--1 span').text(currValue);
    $('.offer__cart__sum--1 span').text(currValue * price)
    if (currValue == 0) {
      $('.offer__cart__count--1').closest('.active').addClass('no-active');
    }
    if (currValue.length === 0) {
      $('.offer__cart__count--1 span').text(0);
      curr.val(0);
    }
  });
  $('.offer__block__calc-2 input').keyup(function(){
    var curr = $(this);
    var currValue = $(this).val();
    $('.offer__cart__count--2').closest('.no-active').removeClass('no-active');
    var price = $('.offer__cart__price__clothes-big').text();
    $('.offer__cart').fadeIn();
    $('.offer__cart__count--2 span').text(currValue);
    $('.offer__cart__sum--2 span').text(currValue * price);
    if (currValue == 0) {
      $('.offer__cart__count--2').closest('.active').addClass('no-active');
    }
    if (currValue.length === 0) {
      $('.offer__cart__count--2 span').text(0);
      curr.val(0);
    }
  });
```

`здесь весь код`https://jsfiddle.net/gcjhnhze/

Comment: Вынесите код в сам вопрос пожалуйста, напишите что он по-вашему должен делать

Comment: Ознакомьтесь пожалуйста с требованиями к вопросам такого типа, тогда помочь вам будет куда проще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первую очередь нужно избавиться от классов типа "add-1" и "add-2". Отличать поведение лучше  по дата-атрибутам (например, data-price="80"), а все события на кнопки и инпуты делать универсальными.

Тогда при добавлении третьего типа останется лишь просто добавить html-элементы и не придётся переписывать js.

После этой ключевой правки код можно будет проще читать и оптимизировать в дальнейшем.

Comment: Как я могу отличить поведение по атрибуту? Можно самый элементарный пример?

Comment: Да, конечно. Например, `<div data-price="80" class="offer__block__calc">`. В js можно обратиться к атрибуту с помощью методов attr() или data(). `var price = $('.offer__block__calc').data('price');`. И уже эту цену ставить в калькулятор или же писать в тексте.

Comment: Спасибо, немного повозившись сделал проверку по атрибутам. Сократил код в два раза!